# What is C# 'internal' in VB.net?

Tags: c#, vb.net, syntax, keyword

What is C# `internal` keyword equivalent in VB.NET?

Answer (score 115, accepted):

It's `Friend`. See the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/76453kax.aspx).

Answer (score 18):

C#'s `internal` in VB.NET is `Friend`.

Answer (score 7):

Basically `Internal` and `Friend` are the same access modifiers in .Net 
where the `Internal` keywords is used in C#.Net and `Friend` is used in VB.Net